# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <post> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm trying to create my first component but i have problem. Any suggestion how can i fix this

This is my jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/hijuyofeko/edit?html,js,output

```
<div id="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="list-group">
      <post v-for="comment in comments" :post="comment"></post>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh wow - you really shouldn't mix vue and jquery in that way. Also your data should actually be a function that returns an object. Please simplify the code to make it easier to determine the actualy problem. Remove everything that is not required. I'd start with not placing everything in a document raedy function